# In an incomplete inner product space, is a closed linear subspace equal to the orthogonal complement of its orthogonal complement?

Tags: functional-analysis, inner-products, orthogonality

It is apparently that this holds in Hilbert space, but I can not prove this for general inner product space or find a counterexample. (The only not complete inner product space known to me is $L^2$ restricted in continuous functions.)

---

[Orthogonal complement of orthogonal complement](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/418271/orthogonal-complement-of-orthogonal-complement)

Here give a example, but it seems don't meet the condition closeness.

---

By the way, Is there any other less complicated spaces equipped with inner product but not complete?

Answer (score 2):

A very simple innner product space which is not Hilbert is the spacee $\phi$ of sequences with only finitely many non-zero terms endowed with the scalar product of $\ell^2$. Let
$L$ be the kernel of the continuous linear functional $x\mapsto \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty x_n/n$
(the scalar product with $(1/n)_{n\in\mathbb N} \in\ell^2\setminus \phi$). 
Then $L^\perp =\lbrace 0\rbrace$: If $y\neq 0$ there is a last index such that $y_n\neq 0$.
Defining $x_n=y_n$, $x_{n+1} = - (1+1/n) \,y_n$ and $x_k=0$ for all other $k$ gives
$x\in L$ and $\langle x,y\rangle = y_n^2\neq 0$, i.e., $y\notin L^\perp$.