# The orthogonal of the orthogonal of a line?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

There is a theorem stating

> $(A^\perp)^\perp=\overline {\text{span}(A)}$
>   where $\overline{\text{span}(A)}$ is the closure of the smallest linear space containing A.

Now, I was applying this to a very simple case.

Let's take a line $l$ orthogonal to a plane $P_1$, and let $P_2$ be an orthogonal plane to $P_1$ containing $l$.

We have that $l^\perp=P_1$ and $P_1^\perp= P_2$.

However, I don't see how $\overline{\text{span}(l)}=P_2$, since the span of $l$ is the line itself, and the closure of a line is again the line itself...

Where is my mistake?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/418271/orthogonal-complement-of-orthogonal-complement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P_1^{\perp}$ is not $P_2$. If you are working in $\mathbb R^{3}$ then $P_1^{\perp}$ is a line not a plane.

Comment: thanks for the answer. could you give me a simple example of a non-closed subspace in R^3?

Comment: In a finite dimensional normed linear space every subspace is closed. @Anoldmaninthesea.

Answer (score 1):

If you can find two planes that are orthogonal to each other, then the ambient space in which they live must have dimension at least $4$, and therefore $l^\perp =P_1$ is impossible, since $l^\perp $ must have dimension at least $3$.

Comment: Arnaud, thanks for the answer, but I think you have a mistake. I agree with your first part. But the orthogonal of a line is in fact a plane in R^3... See the answer by Kabo

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. As I explained, the fact that you have two orthogonal planes implies that the ambient space cannot be $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: Ah... Ok, I get it now, thanks. By the way, could you give an example of a non-closed subspace in R^3?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. Kabo has answered that.